# Grandpa's Numbers

Tags: mathematics, word, no-computers

> Grandpa likes pencils but not pens
>
> Grandpa likes Beijing but not Tokyo
>
> Grandpa likes math but not chemistry

Grandpa likes Contact but not _______

Make sure to explain!

Hint 1:

> Grandpa does not like London

Hint 2:

> Grandpa likes adding (Like actually)

Hint 3:

> Grandpa doesn't just like math; He loves it

Comment: has the final word 7 letters?

Comment: @Jannis It can, I'm just looking for the explanation, and a word that follows the rule (There are multiple)

Answer (score 1):

Grandpa likes pencils but not pens

Grandpa likes Beijing but not Tokyo

Grandpa likes math but not chemistry

Grandpa likes Contact but not

> Flightplan

Explanation:

> Grandpa is old, and therefor only likes old things. Out of any two (similar) things he very much prefers the older one.
>  *pencils* have been around for a long time (they where charcoal sticks at some point), *pens* are a quite recent thing.
>  Beijing was founded ~1000BCE, Tokyo probably in the 14th century.
>  Mathematics was pretty much the first science developed by advanced. Human civilisation, chemistry (as science) only started in the middle ages
>
>  Contact is a movie starring Judie Foster from 1997, Flightplan is from 2005

Comment: This would work, except for the mathematics tag.

Comment: Nice try, but this isn't correct. Think about the hint

Comment: Why is it Flightplan but not other movies? Thanks!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I pretty much just chose a random movie.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, the hint was (kind of) asking for it.

> Grandpa likes Contact but not **London**

Seriously though, this question is a little broad. I came up with a rule that is fairly bullshit (but still follows the tags and such)

> Convert to A1Z26 using [this here converter](https://planetcalc.com/4884/.) and copy/paste it into a new tab. The new tab will interpret the dashes in between letters as minus signs and cough up a number. In case you're too lazy to do it yourself, the number by word is:  
>  
>  pencils: -46 
>  pens: -22 
>  Beijing: -52 
>  Tokyo: -46 
>  math: -16 
>  chemistry: -114 
>  Contact: -70 
>  
>  So, what do they have in common? Well, the last two digits of each number on the left is smaller than the last two digits of its counterpart on the right... Hmm... 
>  
>  A lot of words work for this, but: 
>  London: -50 
>  So I believe London is the answer after all (at least, it's as justified as anything else)!

Comment: hey, just refrain from vulgar language, will you? thanks!